# Join data on client or api server and how?

Tags: c#, database, wpf, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I have an `ASP.NET Core API` and a `WPF` project (both `.NET6`). My API uses a database with `EntityFrameworkCore` and the WPF project is a client that retrieves/sends data from/to the API.

#### Models

The database contains *two tables* generated from two classes: `Class1` and `Class2` (simplified for explanation).

```cs
public class Class1
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(Class2))]
    public Guid Class2Id { get; set; }

    public string PropToDisplay1 { get; set; }
}

public class Class2
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string PropToDisplay2 { get; set; }
}
```

#### View

A view of my client contains a `Datagrid` that I want to use to display `PropToDisplay1` and `PropToDisplay2`. The data context of this view currently only contains a `List` of `Class1` that is linked to the data grid. That will show `PropToDisplay1` and `Class2Id`. Now I want to replace `Class2Id` from `Class1` with `PropToDisplay2` from `Class2`

#### The problem

I implemented a second class that inherits from `Class1` and contains a `Class2` property. So I would have to fetch both classes separately from my API and put them together locally. This seems to be not the best option regarding changes in `Class2` because I would have to fetch everything more than I want to to have everything up to date.

Another way I found is to join these two tables on the server side and then pass them to the client. This seems to be better but I am not sure about how to implement this in my client to allow editing and reduce redundancy.

Comment: "I implemented a second class that inherits from Class1 and contains a Class2 property. " your code as posted does not really reflect that fact

Comment: @tomo_2403: Add navigation properties to your entity types and perform the join on the server?

Comment: @mm8 Thank you for your hint. Never hearted of navigation properties but it seems to be the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your API endpoint to return the joined data: Create an endpoint that performs a join operation on `Class1` and `Class2` and returns the desired data.
For example:

```
[HttpGet("joinedData")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetJoinedData()
{
    var result = await _dbContext.Class1
        .Join(
            _dbContext.Class2,
            c1 => c1.Class2Id,
            c2 => c2.Id,
            (c1, c2) => new
            {
                c1.Id,
                c1.PropToDisplay1,
                c2.PropToDisplay2
            }
        )
        .ToListAsync();

    return Ok(result);
}
```